# DesicionTreeClassifier: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

```
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
scoring = 'accuracy'
score = cross_val_score(clf, train_data, target, cv=k_fold, n_jobs=1, error_score='raise')
print(score)
```

after run this code I have error:

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for
>   dtype('float32').

So how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Decision Trees doesn't accept NaN / infinity values.

Try doing (assuming that `train_data is a Pandas DataFrame`):

```
train_data.fillna(0, inplace = True)
```

This will replace all NaN values by 0.

If you don't want this, the only thing to do is to delete entries with NaN data :

```
train_data.dropna(inplace = True)
```

If this is not a DataFrame, try adding this line before the `fillna` method:

```
train_data = pd.DataFrame(train_data)
```

Comment: but in dataframe I don't have NAN values, maybe its too large for dtype float32?

Comment: C:\Users\Bulisa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\logistic.py:433: FutureWarning: Default solver will be changed to 'lbfgs' in 0.22. Specify a solver to silence this warning.
  FutureWarning)
what does this mean?